# Is there anyway to configure a fixed priority to a rabbitmq binding?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

My setup is the following (two exchanges leading to the same queue):

E1 -> q <- E2

I'm using python/pika

What I'm trying to achieve is to have every message that arrives from E1 be handled with the upmost priority.

I'm trying to achieve that goal with preferably 0 code (I'm trying to avoid writing a super simple bridge that adds in a priority by using as much of AMQ's ability as possible.
I tried using the bindings "arguments" but that did seem to affect anything.
I read al through https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html but did not find a way to affect any of the basic properties via binding arguments. As a matter of fact I couldn't figure out what these argument affect at all.

Thanks!
   Oded